# LWR and flows - they don't go together right?

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, visual-flows, experience-cloud, lwr

Just looking at this Experience Cloud documentation for the first time [LWR - Differences in Behavior](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.exp_cloud_lwr.meta/exp_cloud_lwr/template_differences.htm) and it looks appealing where you want to build all of the UI yourself to have fine grained control, and also pick up performance benefits.

We have some existing flows that are primarily used to allow additional processing steps to be introduced i.e. each flow screen corresponds to an individual LWC with the flow conditions primarily determining where to go next.

Am I correct in assuming that these two things do not fit together today?

**PS**

This video reviews [Building custom navigation and footers for LWR sites](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8WpdllWm__o) explains how to leverage some of the declarative parts of the builder and incorporate that data into custom navigation. So offers a bit, at least for entry point pages.

**PPS**

If I'm interpreting this [IdeaExchange idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdpANUAZ/flow-support-in-lwr-experience) and this [Use Flows in LWR Sites](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=release-notes.rn_experiences_flow_component.htm&type=5&release=238) documentation correctly, **flows do now work in LWR**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Spring 22, LWR Experience Cloud Sites do not have a Flow component available to it's builder, nor is there a way to run a Screen Flow directly from an LWC (not without being coupled with an Aura component)

An autolaunched flow could be triggered by apex that is invoked by the LWC but I don't think that's what you're looking for.

[In a Summer 22 Sneak Preview Post on Unofficialsf](https://unofficialsf.com/summer-22-sneak-peak-flow-orchestrator-nba/), there is a mention that LWR sites will support a Flow component in the builder (with some considerations about flow features that require aura won't work). I haven't yet been able to validate in my prerelease org, but worth noting and looking for

Answer (score 3):

As per summer 22 release notes, Flows are now available in LWR sites, across all LWR templates. With flows, you can harness the unlimited flexibility of Flow Builder to show screen flows on your site. To use flows in LWR, build them with Lightning web components. Flows built with Aura components can’t run in LWR sites.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_experiences_flow_component.htm&type=5&release=238

Answer (score 2):

Yes Lightning Flows are not supported on LWR sites as of Spring 22. There is an [idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdpANUAZ/flow-support-in-lwr-experience) already created for this.

Lightning flows are supported in **Build Your Own (Aura)** template.

---

There is a **workaround** to use Lightning Flows in LWR sites.

Please follow below steps:

1. Embed the Flow in a custom Aura component. Follow [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_using_flow_cmp.htm).
2. Use the Aura Component inside an Aura Application. Create a Visualforce page to use the Aura component. Follow [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm#:%7E:text=Add%20the%20Lightning%20Components%20for,createComponent()%20.)
3. Use the Visualforce page inside an iframe in a LWC. Use the LWC in the LWR site.

---

Comment: Hi Sneh, Thanks for this. That idea asks for a component to achieve this: can you confirm that there is no way to enter a flow from LWR?

Comment: I think you mean "as of Spring 22". Summer 22 is currently in the prerelease window. The summer 22 Sneak preview from the Flow PM team on unofficialsf indicates this feature may be coming in Summer 22 (although I have tried this yet in my summer prerelease org)

Comment: Yes it is Spring 22. Corrected the answer.

Comment: Hi Keith, Jeff, I was reading your answer. I have posted one question, similar to this today here but could not got any answer. Just want to know that I am using customer support theme. I have a case detail page where I have Record banner (compact layout). I have created 2 flows that are using within 2 quick actions. I added the quick action on layout so on standard lightning screen, they are available but on salesforce community case detail page they are not available. Is there any way I can show those 2 quick action there.

Answer (score 1):

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_experiences_flow_component.htm&release=238&type=5

It is officially supported now. LWR is a strict ‘no aura’ environment, which means there cannot be any aura-based local actions or custom aura components in your Flow.
Additionally, Flows with the following screen components / features are not yet supported:

1. File Upload
2. Image
3. Screen Inputs generated using Dynamic Forms for Flow

Flows run in LWR Sites cannot be paused or resumed.